# What guarantees behaviors of operators for slice_array class?

Tags: c++

In `<valarray>` header, five class templates are defined: `valarray`, `slice_array`, `gslice_array`, `mask_array` and `indirect_array`.

For `valarray<Type>` objects, any operators influences all the elements. For example,

```
int array1[] = {1,2,3};
int array2[] = {4,5,6};
valarray<int> v1(array1, 3);
valarray<int> v2(array2, 3);
valarray<int> v3 = v1 + v2; //v3 has 5, 7 and 9.
```

This is the very reason some users use `valarray` instead of other containers like `vector`, and this operator's behavior is described by many reliable websites.

By the way, it is a fact that, also in the rest class templates in `<valarray>`, the operators are overloaded. However, I haven't found any documents in which the behaviors of the operators are described. At least on my environment, the operators behave the same as those of `valarray` class template, but I'd like to get some written evidence.

In reading `<valarray>` header, a sentence `#include <bits/slice_array.h>` is found. And in the `slice_array.h` header, I found the definitions of the operators:

```
  ///  Assign slice elements to corresponding elements of @a v.
  void operator=(const valarray<_Tp>&) const;
  ///  Multiply slice elements by corresponding elements of @a v.
  void operator*=(const valarray<_Tp>&) const;
  ///  Divide slice elements by corresponding elements of @a v.
  void operator/=(const valarray<_Tp>&) const;
  ///  Modulo slice elements by corresponding elements of @a v.
  void operator%=(const valarray<_Tp>&) const;
```

Perhaps these can be a hit, but I don't understand what `@a v` means. (However , this is just an example, but not an evidence.)

Does anyone have the written evidence?

Comment: This information is in the standard or you can consult an online reference site like: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. Do you know what `@a v` means? I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with any standard feature, these operators are defined by the C++ standard.

For example, in C++14:

> `[C++14: 26.6.5.2]` **`slice_array` assignment**                                              `[slice.arr.assign]`
>
> `void operator=(const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `const slice_array& operator=(const slice_array&) const;`
>
> **1** These assignment operators have reference semantics, assigning the values of the argument array elements to selected elements of the `valarray<T>` object to which the `slice_array` object refers.
>
> `[C++14: 26.6.5.3]` **`slice_array` computed assignment**                   `[slice.arr.comp.assign]`
>
> `void operator*= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator/= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator%= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator+= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator-= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator^= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator&= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator|= (const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator<<=(const valarray<T>&) const;`
> `void operator>>=(const valarray<T>&) const;`
>
> **1** These computed assignments have reference semantics, applying the indicated operation to the elements of the argument array and selected elements of the `valarray<T>` object to which the `slice_array` object refers.

The documenting comment, on the other hand, has nothing to do with the standard and was a choice by the author of your particular implementation/toolchain. The `@a` is almost certainly [a doxygen directive](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmda).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.